# Change the shape of the "solidify" edge

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry-nodes, solidify-modifier

community! I need to solidify the flat mesh but the edge should have some C-shape on it. I know it is supposed to be done with GN, and I saw the solution some time ago, but I can't find it anywhere now when I actually need it. So here's the approximate sketch of what I need (yellow overdraw) and the nodes that I have by far, that are providing me the flat edge. I need to add some loops on the thickness edge and bend them (preferably controlling with the curve).

Any advise?

[image]